# Percentage of values changed in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, percentage

A) `.originalData` is a textarea

B) `.changedData` is also a textarea but this is were I will be making the changes

**How could I calculate a percentage of the values changed in B starting at 0%?**

**jQuery:**

`var changed, original = $(".originalData").val() $(".changedData").change(function(){ changed = $(this).val(); });`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to calculate the percent of changes i guess you have to do something like this

```
var changedData = $('.changedData').val().length;
var originalData = $('.changedData').val().length;

var precentageOfChange = changedData/originalData * 100 - 100
$('.mydiv').append(precentageOfChange);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.changedData').change(function(){
   var original = $('.originalData').val();
   var changed = $(this).val();
   var changed = changed / original * 100 - 100;
});
```

Comment: using val() will return the value of the text-area not the numbers